# Is it possible to place an image anywhere on the page?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to place an image anywhere on the page WITHOUT USING `POSITION:RELATIVE`?

Thanks

Comment: With position:fixed;

Comment: Sure: `position: absolute;`. Also: `transform: translate(`…`, `…`)`.

Comment: If i use position:absolute will it leave a blank space like position:relative?

Comment: How can I use transform:translate to move an image?

Comment: @MrPotato _“How can I use `transform:translate` to move an image?”_ The first step is to use Google.

Comment: lol i did but didnt understand

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments above:

```
position: fixed;
```

or apply `position: absolute;` if the parent element doesn't have `position: relative;` applied.

Comment: parent element doesnt have position:absolute

Comment: Great! But does the parent have `position: relative;` ?